# Limit the number of characters of a String parameter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a method which accepts a String as an argument. How can I indicate that this parameter can only have an X amount of characters?

```
fun logEvent(name: String) {
    require(name.length <= 40) { "Event name $name is too long!" }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Size](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Size) annotation of [androidx.annotation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation):

```kotlin
fun logEvent(@Size(max = 40) name: String)
    require(name.length <= 40) { "Event name $name is too long!" }
}
```

You can set `min`, `max`, `multiple` and `value` (with which you can specify a specific length). This will trigger a nice warning in your IDE when appropriate. It's just a warning though: the code will still run and accept Strings of any size.

Comment: Note it can only warn you about hard-coded Strings and constants.